# Does SharePoint 2013 support SQL 2014 SP2?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does SharePoint 2013 support SQL 2014 SP2? if so can anyone point me to the microsofts link?

Thanks

Comment: Check the list of all **[Supported and Unsupported SQL Server for SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/#sql-server-version-for-sharepoint-2013)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. SharePoint 2013 w/ the May 2014 CU (or SP1) support SQL Server 2014 and all subsequent SQL Server 2014 Service Packs.

Microsoft only provides a baseline minimum for SQL Server products, which might include a Service Pack. But all subsequent Service Packs for that SQL Server product are supported.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - can you provide me with a link to microsoft with this info?

Comment: Microsoft only provides baseline and maximum requirements based on SQL versions.